# How to produce HTML from a list

Tags: common-lisp, cl-who

The usual way to generate HTML using [CL-WHO](https://edicl.github.io/cl-who/) is by using the macros `with-html-output` and `with-html-output-to-string`. This uses special syntax. For example:

```lisp
(let ((id "greeting")
      (message "Hello!"))
  (cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
    ((:p :id id) message)))
```

Is it possible to write the data `((:p :id id) message)` as a list instead of using the macro syntax shown above? For example, I would like to define the HTML as a list like this:

```lisp
(let* ((id "greeting")
       (message "Hello!")
       (the-html `((:p :id ,id) ,message)))
  ;; What should I do here to generate HTML using CL-WHO?
  )
```

Can CL-WHO take a normal Lisp list and produce HTML from the list?

Comment: You might like [Ten](https://github.com/mmontone/ten), it's a templating engine but we can write any Lisp inside it. Could be a middle ground for you, you will be able to write `the-html` with the placeholders and already with some logic.

Comment: AllegroServe's htmlgen is able to generate HTML from Lisp lists, but it's only for Allegro Common Lisp. There's a "Portable AllegroServe" fork of AllegroServe that supports other Common Lisp implementations, but it appears to be unmaintained and its htmlgen still does not support HTML5.

Comment: Looks like [Flute](https://github.com/ailisp/flute) allows that. Its building blocks are just functions, so we can pass in variables.

Comment: There's [html.lisp](https://gist.github.com/markasoftware/ab357f1b967b3f656d026e33fec3bc0e), which generates HTML from lists.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert code into an expression.

Actually you would need eval:

```
(let* ((id "greeting")
       (message "Hello!")
       (the-html `((:p :id ,id) ,message)))
  (eval `(cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
    ,the-html)))
```

But this is not good to use `eval`.
But a macro contains an implicite `eval`.
I would define a macro for this and call the macro:

```
(defun html (&body body)
  `(cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
    ,@body))

;; but still one doesn't get rid of the `eval` ...
;; one has to call:
(let* ((id "greeting")
       (message "Hello!")
       (the-html `((:p :id ,id) ,message)))
  (eval `(html ,the-html)))
```

Comment: How do I use the `html` macro? `(html the-html)` returns an empty string.

Comment: One would need an `apply`or `funcall`  which can take macros instead of functions - to get rid of the `eval` ...